# Is there a way in SQLite to get the number of rows a select will return?

Tags: sqlite

Sql Server has this nice thing that for any select of any complexity you can get a count of the number of rows it would return. You give it the select:

```
string.Format("select count (*) from ({0}) as numrows", selectBody);
```

And it returns a number. Does SQLite have something similar?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. SQLite supports that syntax. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

But I would suggest to name the result column:

```
select count(*) as numrows from ({0})
```

Rather than:

```
select count(*) from ({0}) as numrows
```

gives `({0})` the table the alias `numrows`.